# Perform different operations on sections of the same image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagej

I have a grayscale image from a neutron radiography dataset. I want to divide the image into different sections as shown in the image below, divide each section by a different number and do a colormap showing the final intensity values on the complete image? How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Different sections of same size? How about use sample input data and show us the expected output?

Comment: How you want to difine the dividing to sections?

Comment: I cannot post a picture here because I do not have a reputation of 10 yet. But, I have to divide them into sections of different sizes.

Comment: post a link to the image and someone with higher reputation will include it

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/24qr72o/8

Comment: @user2542878 - There is no image at that link.  Try using http://postimg.org instead.

Comment: @rayryeng Image added

Comment: Those definitions in the image look completely arbitrary. Can you provide insight on how you came up with these regions?

Answer (score 2):

In ImageJ, to divide a section of an image by a value, create a rectangular selection, then use the Process > Math > Divide... command. You can repeat this for all desired sections.

You can use the [Macro Recorder](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#The_recorder) to record a macro of these operations, such that they can be automated across any number of sections, assuming you have a programmatic way of computing these sections (rather than just drawing them by hand).

You can then apply a color map using the commands in the Image > Lookup Tables menu.